# JS read object from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

> CODE:

```
let name = 'bam'; 
doc.name = req.body[x].value;
```

> PROBLEM:

I want it to return `doc.bam` value but actually it get `doc.name` value while I set `name='bam'`.

Answer (score 1):

For computed properties you should use `[]`

```js
var doc = {};
let name = 'bam'; 
doc[name] = "abc";

console.log(doc.bam);
```

Comment: why are you using these much variables, doc['bam'] = "abc"; this is enough for your answer

Comment: @AkhilAravind this example is made to make the op understand how to use dynamic properties in an object :-)

Comment: There are dozens of duplicate answers for this question.